# Why Liferay ask credentials also for a public Site page?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-6.2

Strange navigations. Using Liferay CE 6.2.3 GA4, in a Portal instance www.portal.com I created a Site other than the base Guest site. The new Site is "Open" and I assigned it a virtual host name of www.site.com. Public and private three have a single home page.

If the user navigate to www.site.com he/she see the public home, then if he/she do a login the landing page is the Home page of the Guest base site of www.portal.com. Why ?

Then in "My sites" if the User click on the private side of www.site.com he/she need to give the credentials again. Very strange...

Ok, then the user is on the private home of www.site.com but if the User in "My Sites" click on the public side of www.site.com he/she need to give the credentials again ! This because the "My Sites" portlet is not on the right upper corner, instead there is the "Sign in" link". Very wrong ...

Please anyone can help me ?

Thank you in advance !
Ivano C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues mentioned here. Answering the issues that I understand.

> **1.** If the user navigate to www.site.com he/she see the public home, then if he/she do a login the landing page is the Home page of the Guest base site of www.portal.com. Why ?

By default it takes to default Guest Site after login.

You can change default landing page URL in Control Panel →
Configuration → Portal Settings. If you want custom behaviour then
you can implement post login hook.

> **2.** Then in "My sites" if the User click on the private side of www.site.com he/she need to give the credentials again. Very strange...

As there are two different host names [`www.portal.com` & `www.site.com`]
and clicking on links that directs from one site to the other makes it
as two different sites. Hence it asks for login again.

Comment: Thank you Haris for your replies but after some searches I'm thinking that I have to explore a SSO solution, since in fact I'm in the presence of two separate web site and I need one single log in